# c# variable and string for file location cannot join

Tags: c#, string, variables

I have the string below that works fine:

```
/* Upload a File */
ftpClient.upload(GetPublicIpAddress() + ".stats." + userName + ".dat", @"C:\Users\variable\AppData\Roaming\miner\stants.dat");
```

I am trying to change it so where it says

```
users\variable\AppData
```

it substitutes the user's name for 'variable'. I have this below

```
variable = userName
/* Upload a File */
ftpClient.upload(GetPublicIpAddress() + ".stats." + userName + ".dat", @"C:\Users\"+ userName +"\AppData\Roaming\miner\stants.dat");
```

I get the following error

```
Error   3   Unrecognized escape sequence    C:\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs
```

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a second @ symbol.

```
ftpClient.upload(GetPublicIpAddress() + ".stats." + userName + ".dat", @"C:\Users\"+ userName +@"\AppData\Roaming\miner\stants.dat");
```

Once you split the string into 2, you need to prefix both strings with @.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @ after the userName when you concatenate it.